# Define when class is truthy/falsy in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to define when my class is truthy/falsy. Is it possible?

```
class CustomNullObject
  def nil?
    true
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
puts CustomNullObject.new ? 'ignore me' : 'PRINT ME! NullObject is falsy'
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like `new` method for `CustomNullObject` should return true of false.

Comment: That's bad idea. New should return new instance of its class (or throw expcetion?) It's not answer to my question anyway.